# Indexing into the last axis of a 3D array with another 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

if i have an array **x**, which value is as follow with shape **(2,3,4)**:

```
array([[[ 0.15845319,  0.57808432,  0.05638804,  0.56237656],
        [ 0.73164208,  0.80562342,  0.64561066,  0.15397456],
        [ 0.34734043,  0.88063258,  0.4863103 ,  0.09881028]],

       [[ 0.35823078,  0.71260357,  0.49410944,  0.94909165],
        [ 0.02730397,  0.67890392,  0.74340148,  0.47434223],
        [ 0.02494292,  0.59827256,  0.20550867,  0.30859339]]])
```

and i have an index array **y**, which shape is **(2, 3, 3)**, and the value is:

```
array([[[0, 2, 2],
        [2, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[1, 2, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2]]])
```

so i could use **x[0,0,y[0][0]]** to index the array **x**, and it will generate the output as follow:

```
array([ 0.15845319,  0.05638804,  0.05638804])
```

my question is: is there any simple way to do this? i had already tried with
**x[y]**, it did not work.

Comment: write a small function to implement the abbreviation?

Comment: i want to do it in an easy way, not a function, just look like the question i post here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118401/slice-operation-for-numpy-in-python2).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`fancy-indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) -

```
m,n = y.shape[:2]
out = x[np.arange(m)[:,None,None],np.arange(n)[:,None],y]
```